InLine кнопки в telebot
@bot.message_handler()
def point1(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я не робот', callback_data='True')
    markup.add(button1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Подтверждение действия', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def captcha(call):
    if call.data == 'True':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Доступ в архив разрешен...')


@bot.message_handler()
def check(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Прочитано✅', callback_data='True')
    markup.add(button1)
    bot.send_message(message.message.chat.id, 'АРХИВ', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def recaptcha(call):
    if call.data == 'True':
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='КОНЕЦ')

Как сделать так, чтобы после надписи "Доступ в архив разрешен" у меня запускалась функция check(message)
